Losing print jobs
In 22.04, I used to bring up the printers app and disable the printer when it is off (I am in a home office and do not leave the printer on all the time, saves power).  In 24.04, that feature is gone.  However, I am now losing print jobs when the printer is off.  Losing printing of invoices and bills is a very serious issue for me.  Anyone know how I can disable/enable the printer like I could in 22.04; or change some attribute that does not cause me to loose jobs?

I did find that I could install system-config-printer and get the old printer tool back.  But it is deprecated, so it is just a bypass for my problem.
